# AngularJS filter in controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have this angular loop and controller:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: post._creator = getCurrentUser"></li>
```

and Controller:

```
    $http.get('/api/posts').success(function(posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts;
        $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser()._id;
    });
```

It is possible to inject the filter in the controller?

What is the best practice?

Comment: You mean using the `$filter`?

Comment: Can you detail a little bit, maybe some examples?

Comment: Yes you can use filter in js.

Comment: `$filter("yourFilterName")(argument)`

Comment: how can I filter the posts who have ._creator = loggedIn user in the arguments, thats the part I dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dedicated file filers.js and put filters registration code into the file.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ftFilters', [])
.filter('rub', function() {
    return function (value) {
        if (value === undefined || value === null){
            return 'не задана';
        }
        return value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ").replace('.','<small>,') + '</small> руб';
    };
})
.filter('rudate', function($filter) {
    var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
    return function(theDate) {
       return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss');
    }
});
```

then you must add this module into dependencies for your application, e.g.

```
'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
        // Init module configuration options
        var applicationModuleName = 'ft';
        var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',
        'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'vr.directives.slider', 'ya.treeview', 'ui.select', 'ftFilters' ];

        // Add a new vertical module
        var registerModule = function(moduleName) {
                // Create angular module
                angular.module(moduleName, []);

                // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
                angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
        };

        return {
                applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
                applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
                registerModule: registerModule
        };
})();
```

after this you can use it everywhere